# Accessing parent property inside parent class throws error - using $this when not in object context

Tags: php, oop

Parent Class

```
class admarvel_generic_network
{
    protected $attributeSettings;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->attributeSettings = "something";
    }

    public static function parentGetAd()
    {
        print_r($this->attributeSettings); //throws FATAL ERROR Using $this when not in object context 
    }

}
```

Child Class - Initiating object of same class within static function

```
class Agencies_selectablemedia_test extends admarvel_generic_network
{
    public static function getAd($frengoAdParams)
    {
        $adnw = new Agencies_selectablemedia_test();
        $ad = $adnw->parentGetAd();

        return $ad;
    }
}   


//Entry point
$ad_contents = Agencies_selectablemedia_test::getAd($params);

echo $ad_contents;
```

I get a fatal error, as highlighted in the code above.

I checked that if I make the following changes in child and parent class -

Parent Class

```
public static function parentGetAd($obj)
        {
            print_r($obj->attributeSettings); //this works
        }
```

Child Class

```
public static function getAd($frengoAdParams)
        {
            $adnw = new Agencies_selectablemedia_test();
            $ad = admarvel_generic_network::parentGetAd($adnw); //used scope resolution operator and passed object as parameter.

            return $ad;
        }
```

Could someone explain the above? I would like to understand why I cannot use $this->attributeSettings in the parent class's parentGetAd() function.

Comment: You can't use `$this` inside a static function. `$this` is used by object instances, not static calls as calling statically doesn't produce an instance..

Comment: there's no need to instantiate the parent class...

Comment: @ShiguriAnemone', any reasons for that? We will need to access parent properties inside functions of parent class, and may need to overwrite those functions in child class.

Comment: @SandeepanNath he extends on the parentClass...  he can now use the public function of the parent class.... by using `$this`. in his case he should be doing the static call.. something like `childClass::getAd()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you cannot access `$this->attributeSettings` is that your are in a static method. So you aren't in the context of an object.

```
public static function parentGetAd($obj)
```

If you are declaring the method like this

```
public function parentGetAd($obj) {

}
```

you should be able to access `$this->attributeSettings`.

Comment: Oh, my bad.. basics of OOPs :(